# Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase

We have an app that was rejected due to Guideline 3.1.1 from Apple.

The app is a free alumni app for a school. Once users install the build, the app requires entering a password to access the contents of the app.

We have the password requirement as a way to verify only alumni users to access the app.

This is not an in-purchase app as we are not selling contents of the app.

Can anyone suggest a solution so that our app doesn't get rejected?

Comment: Where you able to resolve this matter ? @maki

Answer (score 0):

Replace single password with login-password pair, where only correct pair will open access to data. App should have possibility for register new account, but users registered this way could get just common information.